# MongoDB Node.js module 'mongo' is not recognised as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am following Node.js tutorials by Code Academy from Youtube and am currently on video number 19. There you can see at 3:10 he typed mongo and then it switched to the database.

But in my case its giving the following error `'mongo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` Why is this happening?

I followed the steps exactly as shown in the video. To throw a light, in my case, its connected to the database and 2 documents are inserted (as shown). But in next step its giving this error. Please help me devs.

Answer (score 21):

You have to add the mongo executable to PATH, so the commands are accessible from outside the MongoDB bin folder.

Search for your MongoDb installation bin folder and copy the path (e.g.: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\bin)
Right click My Computer > Properties > Advanced system settings > Environment Variables > System variables > Look for "Path" > Edit > New > Paste in the path to your Mongodb bin folder > Restart your terminal

EDIT:

A faster way to get to the Environment Variables is to press Start on Windows and type **"env"** and then select **"Edit environment variables"** or **"Edit system variables"**. No need really, to set the Path system wide if you don't have the privileges.

EDIT 2:

As some have stated, the path of mongo from version 4.0 changed a little:
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin

Comment: MongoDB executeables will be found in  "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin"

Comment: It works. Feb 2021

Answer (score 6):

If you use Windows you need to add mogo (C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin) to PATH Env then close terminal and open again.....mongo --version should work

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have install mongodb software. You can download the software for your operating system using the following official link:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation/

For windows users, follow the instructions of the following official link:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

Comment: you answered so fast.. thanks.. I hope it helps others.. :)

Comment: @ShubhamJha ;)...I know it is late...I found the question helpful and related to my problem, but not the answer, that's why I posted my answer to help others...

Comment: that's nice of you.. you didn't cared about the post date of the question but about solving other peoples troubles.. good spirit of helping.. :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all , "mongo" is not a node.js module.

```
'mongo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,    operable program or batch file.
```

This error is because your system doesnt recognize the command "mongo"

If you want to connect to database from terminal/cmd, check that the database path is included in your environment variable and then run command "mongo", or open the directory where mongodb is installed and access it from there